# Simulate an example showing difference between fixed effects and mixed effects models

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to find an example with extreme differences in model results when fixed effects are used instead of random effects. I tried to simulate an example with the following code:

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
df <- data.frame(Group=LETTERS[1:10]) %>%
  mutate(yGroup=rnorm(n()), xGroup=rnorm(n())) %>%                  # group means
  mutate(coefGroup=rnorm(n(), mean=.25)) %>%                        # group slope
  mutate(size=sample(5:10, 1)) %>% uncount(size) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(x=xGroup + rnorm(n()), y=yGroup + coefGroup * x + rnorm(n(), sd=.5))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=Group)) + geom_point()
lm(y ~ x + Group, data=df) %>% tidy()

lmod1 <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|Group), data=df)
lmod2 <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1|Group), data=df)
anova(lmod1, lmod2)
```

However, whatever I do, the differences in the effects or coefficients from OLS and mixed effects model are very similar. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong.

Fitting fixed effects for a grouping variable, instead of random intercepts, is a perfectly valid approach, so the results you get will be comparable.

So you might wonder: why bother fitting a mixed effects model at all ? The answer to that is when the number of groups becomes large you don't really want to fit fixed effects because you then end up with a large number of estimates. Also, you will consume a large number of degrees of freedom. Also, Occam's Razor dictates that a more parsimoneous model should be preferrd, other things being equal, and with a large number of groups, a fixed effects model is far from parsimoneous.